# Number of Involutive Automorphisms on a Clifford Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, clifford-algebras

Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension $n$ and $q$ a quadratic form on $V$. How many involutive automorphisms are there in $\mathcal{C} \ell (V,q)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, infinitely many.

Take for example $\Bbb H$, which is a Clifford algebra for a suitable choice of metric on $\Bbb R^2$. Pick any unit length quaternion $u$ with real part $0$. Then $(u\cos(\pi/2)-\sin(\pi/2))^2=1$.

There are as many choices for $u$ as there are points on the unit sphere in $3$-space.

Each of these will describe an involution given by $x\mapsto uxu^{-1}$

Comment: Minor clarification: $u$ and $-u$ get identified for the induced involutions. Still infinitely many involutions.